# How does google NOW parses E-Mail's, to generate NOW notifications - cards

Tags: google-schemas

How can I change the E-Mail header settings in the emails sent by a train company - e.g. Deutsche Bahn, so the mail receiver with Google now enabled would get a now card.

It works great with Amazon and flight bookings, but there seems no "Train or railway" Schema to exist so far?

Answer (score 0):

I was testing out the [TrainReservation schema](https://developers.google.com/schemas/reference/train-reservation) the other day and I was able to generate a Now card using the sample below:

```html
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "TrainReservation",
  "reservationNumber": "12345",
  "reservationStatus": "http://schema.org/ReservationConfirmed",
  "reservationFor": {
    "@type": "TrainTrip",
    "departureStation": {
      "@type": "TrainStation",
      "name": "Munich Central"
    },
    "departureTime": "2015-05-26T10:30:00+01:00",
    "arrivalStation": {
      "@type": "TrainStation",
      "name": "Paris Gare De Lyon"
    },
    "arrivalTime": "2015-05-27T03:10:00+01:00"
  },
  "reservedTicket": {
    "@type": "Ticket",
    "underName": "Eva Green",
    "ticketedSeat": {
      "@type": "Seat",
      "seatNumber": "27B",
      "seatingType": "1st Class"
    },
    "ticketNumber": "123XYZ",
    "ticketToken": "aztecCode:AB34",
    "additionalTicketText": "We recommend that you arrive at the station at least 30 minutes prior to your scheduled departure. Allow additional time if you need help with baggage or tickets."
  }
}
</script>
```

Here's a screenshot of the result on my HTC One Android device:

[image]

Note, that this will not appear in Gmail/Inbox like the FlightReservation. You will only be able to generate a Now card.